# Linear Algebra: Determine whether this set is a generating set for R^n

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Isn't this wrong? This is inconsistent and therefore S does not generate R^3.

Right?

Comment: you're mistaking the coefficient matrix $A$ for the augmented matrix $[A\,|\,v]$. that bottom row of three 0's and a -4 doesn't make the system inconsistent because that's only the coefficient matrix, not the augmented matrix.

Comment: OMG. You are right. So many hours of studying for finals, I over thought this. My mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems a perfect solution.

The row reductions correspond to elementary *basis transformations* on $\Bbb R^3$: starting out from the standard basis $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$, $e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$, $e_3=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$, we do the following similar (inverse) steps to the basis, and coordinate the *same* four vectors in the new basis:

- $R_2\,\to\, R_2+3\,R_1$ corresponds to $e_1' :=e_1-3e_2$ (so that, indeed the first vector becomes $-e_1'$).
- $R_3\,\to\,R_3-R_2$ corresponds to $e_2':=e_2+e_3$.

Since these always remain basis, the vectors $-e_1',\,e_2',2e_1'+5e_2'-4e_3$ also form a basis, in particular they span all vectors of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I still don't understand. So on step 4, the bottom row [0 0 0 -4] is inconsistent. Does this not matter?

Comment: @Sol: see my comment above. you're mixing up the difference between the coefficient matrix and the augmented matrix.